# NestJS+TypeORM - Access Repo from Subscriber (trying to imitate Triggers)

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm on my first projet using NestJS and I'm a bit confused.

I have 2 entities: `Account` and `Transaction`

how should I implement a way to update `Account.balance` on changes (Create, Update, Delete) in `Transactions`

Looks like I should create a `TransactionsSubscriber` but there I can't seem to access DB connection.

Subscribers are loaded in the `ormconfig.json`

I feel I'm missing out something obvious, but I've been stuck there for too long. Please someone help me out.

```js
@EventSubscriber()
export class TransactionsSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<TransactionEntity> {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection('Account') readonly connection: Connection,
    @InjectRepository(TransactionEntity) transactionsRepo: Repository<TransactionEntity>,
    // @InjectEventEmitter() private emitter: AppEventEmitter,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request,
  ) {
    // connection.subscribers.push(this);
    console.log(
      typeof connection, // <=== ** here it returns me undefined **
      typeof transactionsRepo // and here too
      //, typeof emitter
    );
  }

  /**
   * Indicates that this subscriber only listen to TransactionEntity events.
   */
  listenTo() {
    return TransactionEntity;
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<TransactionEntity>) {
    console.log(`After Transaction INSERTED: `, event.entity);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request` in subscribe constructor as [subscribers can not be request-scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#subscribers).
You shouldn't use `ormconfig.json` file to bind you subscriber.
Add subscriber to module providers:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UsersService, TransactionsSubscriber],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Comment: So there is no way to get request context inside subscribers?